# How to combine to json arrays

Tags: android, arrays, json

In order to combine 2 JSON arrays into one I use the following code (the input data areJSON arrays that wereconverted to a string)

```
private static String combineData(String Data, String data){
    if (empty(data))
        data = Data;
    else {  // need to append the data
        try {
// first, convert the strings back to JSON objects
            JSONObject jsonObj1 = new JSONObject(data); // existing data
            JSONObject jsonObj2 = new JSONObject(Data); // new data
            // Getting Array of Providers
            String fieldName = context.getString(R.string.JSON_COMP_RECORDS);
// Second, get the array out of the JSON object
            JSONArray record1 = jsonObj1.getJSONArray(fieldName);
            JSONArray record2 = jsonObj2.getJSONArray(fieldName);
// Third, join them into one array
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
 // LOOP 1 - get individual JSON objects
            for (int i = 0; i < record1.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c;
                try {
                    c = record1.getJSONObject(i);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return data;
                }
                arr.put (c);
            }
 // LOOP 1 - get individual JSON objects
            for (int i = 0; i < record2.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c;
                try {
                    c = record2.getJSONObject(i);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return data;
                }
                arr.put (c);
            }
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put (context.getString(R.string.JSON_COMP_RECORDS), arr);
            data = json.toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to do it more efficiently and get rid of the 2 loops?

Comment: Looking at it more closely than my previously unhelpful comment, yes - create a new function. You'd  use just the for loop in the function. You'd have to pass String data to it as that is part of the catch (I don't like passing around variables within functions but oh well). You can return c which is then put into the array, rather than passing around the array. I'd write it as an answer, but my Java is rusty so I'll leave that to someone else.

Comment: @SagePawan. Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 0):

How about this ? You can put JSONObject directly int another array

```
JSONArray record1 = jsonObj1.getJSONArray(fieldName);
JSONArray record2 = jsonObj2.getJSONArray(fieldName);
for (int i = 0; i < record1.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c;
    try {
          c = record1.getJSONObject(i);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          return data;
    }
     record2.put (c);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
JSONArray record1 = jsonObj1.getJSONArray(fieldName);
JSONArray record2 = jsonObj2.getJSONArray(fieldName);

for (int i = 0; i < record1.length(); i++) {    
    record2.put(record1.getJSONObject(i));
}
```